# Guidance on data source(s) for my project

Tags: c#, sql, xml, winforms

I'm a novice programmer. I am full of theoretical knowledge, but I'm behind with the practice. OK. I am trying to make a program for adding categories and descriptions to files. The language is C#, it should run on Windows 7...

1.The categories can contain sub-categories.

I don't want to call them "tags", because these are different. A category can be fx "favorites". But it can also be: "favorites->music->2013". You can create sub-categories, I will use a TreeView on a WinForm for all the operations a user can do with them.

QUESTION: Should I use XML file for the categories?

2.Every file CAN have a description and one or many categories. However:

- Even if the file is deleted, I want to keep its description, so that it can be available for later usage.
- Folders themselves will be omitted. The folders themselves cannot have nor categories, nor description. But the contained files YES.

I made a very simple SQL Server database containing one table: !http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/3931/finalprojectdb.png

QUESTION: Is this a good idea? Maybe the categories column is better to be of type XML ?

Any advice on what should the best approach in this situation be, is welcomed. Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is something critical I need to know and then I can give you a standard, tried-and-true method of storing your data. From that point, there's many standard methods of creating treeviews and other navigation. So... can a subcategory be subordinate to more than one category? That is: if you have "Music->2013" and also "Photos->2013" are those both the same "2013" tag or are there two "2013" tags?

Comment: In this example we talk about two different categories, yes :)

Comment: Actually I don't know if having "2013" as a standalone category "behind the scenes" could be a good idea. But what the user should eventually see is the "built" category "Photos->2013", a category that he has made by using the TreeView to create "2013" as a child of "Photos".The menu gives the tree structure, but from that the user gets the whole category in the form of string: "Photos->2013".
So how to deal with all this is what I'm trying to find out :)

Comment: OK, I think what you're looking for is a variation on this CTE technique.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21082/Concatenate-Field-Values-in-One-String-Using-CTE-i

Answer (score 0):

SQL is not great for getting nested data at once. You can store things in XML which gives you a lot of flexibility, but you also have to write a parser or deserializer for it. Nowadays people also just write a little Javascript class and use something like Newtonsoft to deserialize it automatically.

If you want a DB solution, you can use something like SQLite embedded in your application if you don't want to install a database separately.

Answer (score 0):

XML is a great design for an app that needs to communicate cross platform (say c# to java), or cross internet, or cross network.  But as a way to store data as a subset in a table, not really.

A normalized database is a terrific tool.  It can be indexed (xml can not) this allows for rapid querying of data.  If you de-normalize your data by embedding xml in a column querying it will be slow and updating / maintaining a pain.

I personally prefer foreign key tables.

Comment: As much I like having fun with LINQ to XMl :D I also recognize the advantages of the database. Now, with that being said, how to store the information about all the categories one file can have ? I try to think about tables and keys, but just can't come with a good model.

Comment: What you need is a recursive table with a foreign key to a details table.